# Django form instance is missing a field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So I have a problem. I have a model form:

```
class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Team
    fields = ['name','category','association','division','gender','logo','season']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(TeamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)

    utils = CPUtils()
    season_utils = SeasonUtils()

    if instance and instance.pk is None:
        self.fields['division'].initial = 1
        self.fields['season'].initial = season_utils.getCurrentSeason().id

        if user_role != 'admin':
            self.fields['division'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['division'].required = False

            self.fields['season'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['season'].required = False
```

So I am setting the initial of the form for the field season.
On my form, it is showing just fine.

So now in my clean method, I want to run some validation and I need to get the instance season.

In my clean method:

```
    if cleaned_data.get('season') is None:
        cleaned_data['season'] = self.instance.season
```

But it says that self.instance.season: DoesNotExist: Team has no season.

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and I have no idea what's going on...

EDIT: 
Here my model:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=25,verbose_name=_("name"))
slug = AutoSlugField(unique=True,populate_from='name')
season = models.ForeignKey(Season,verbose_name=_("season"),blank=False)
association = models.ForeignKey(Association,blank=False,null=True,verbose_name=_("association"),on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category,verbose_name=_("category"),blank=False,null=True,default=1,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
division = models.ForeignKey(Division,verbose_name=_("division"),blank=False,null=True,default=1,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Also, the instance does not have season only during create and not during update...

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: How does your model look like?

Comment: @AshishKasturia I added it to the question. Thanks

Comment: Can you try to initialize `season` with `season_utils.getCurrentSeason()` without it's `id`?

Comment: @AshishKasturia I tried it and it doesn the same thing..

Comment: Is this code `if cleaned_data.get('season') is None:` in the view to create a new Team?

Comment: @AshishKasturia It's in my clean method in my form

Comment: Is it because `instance`, which is an instance of the model `Team` hasn't been saved yet?

Comment: Oh wow... I am so dumb sometimes. I am going to go bang my head on the wall now. Thanks!

Comment: It happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it says:

*self.instance.season: DoesNotExist*

Is that you are accessing `self`.  `Self` here is actually the **Form**, and you are asking the **Form** for an attribute called `instance`, and then asking the `instance` attribute if it has a `season` attribute. The Form doesn't have this attribute.

What you really want to do is get the Model instance based on the Season ID, not the Form instance.  The Form instance only holds the data temporarily while you clean it before you use the Model to save it to the database.

If you are trying to `clean()` the season, then you would want to access it this way if `Season` is an `ID` in your Form:

```
class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    # form logic here

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(TeamForm, self).clean()

        # now get the Season Object from the cleaned_data dictionary 
        #   if 'season' == season_id
        try:
            season_id = cleaned_data['season']
            season = Season.object.get(pk=season_id)
        except KeyError:
            # season id does not exist, so do something here
            pass
```

Comment: Hi, Yeah that's exactly what I did :)

Comment: Great. Yea, it took me a minute to understand the Form/Model concept, but once you do then it helps a lot!